# Keyboard appearance pushes scrollView content

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, appearance

I need that when keyboard appears it will push scrollView (Message bubbles or messages) up too. It pushes textfield only. Which approach is good? And also how to make that when MessageView appears scrollView starts from bottom, not from top as default?

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import CoreData

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 4) {
                    ForEach(messagesViewModel.messages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        let isLastMessage = index == messagesViewModel.messages.indices.last
                        MessageBubble(message: messagesViewModel.messages[index],
                                      isLastMessage: isLastMessage,
                                      isLastBeforeDirectionChange: false,
                                      swipeOffset: $swipeOffset)
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 50)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            if !isVerticalDragInProgress && abs(value.translation.width) > abs(value.translation.height) {
                                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                                    swipeOffset = min(0, max(value.translation.width, -60))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            if !isVerticalDragInProgress {
                                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                    swipeOffset = 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
        }
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                TextField("New Message", text: $newMessage, axis: .vertical)
                    .autocorrectionDisabled()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(background)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30))
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(gradient, lineWidth: 1.3)
                    )
                
                if newMessage.isEmpty {
                    Button(action: {
                        if isMicButton {
                            // Send Audio Message
                        } else {
                            // Send Video Message
                        }
                        withAnimation(Animation.bouncy(duration: 0.1, extraBounce: 0.3)) {
                            isMicButton.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: isMicButton ? "mic.fill" : "video.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color(hex: "#fffcf2").opacity(0.5) : Color(hex: "#415675"))
                    }
                } else {
                    Button(action: {
                        messagesViewModel.sendMessage(text: newMessage)
                        newMessage = ""
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color(hex: "#fffcf2").opacity(0.5) : Color(hex: "#415675"))
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(7)
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    .navigationBarTitle(contactName, displayMode: .inline)
    
   }
}
```

**I tried to wrap scrollview and HStack into the VStack, not working.**
Should I use SafeArea? And how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide a code that would compile for the community to help you.